# Issues with images loaded from URL in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrequest

So I'm making a Twitch/Unity integration game, and I'm using the function below to grab the image from the web and apply it to a material on a GameObject. I have two problems however:

1. The background for the emotes are not transparent in game and become very distorted. I can't figure out how to fix that. This is what the image looks like in the application once the command calls (see the background).

[image]

2. There are BTTV emotes that are GIFs instead of PNGs. I have a way to determine which one it is, but I don't know what to do about the GIFs. Ideally I would have them play animated but I think a lot more realistically is to just have it show the first frame. I also don't know how to do that though.

```
IEnumerator GetTexture(string url)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        Texture2D img = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
        img.alphaIsTransparency = true; // this is here because I was trying to fix the transparent background, it did  not help.
        spriteCubeTest.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = img;
    }
```

If anyone knows how to fix these things I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I ended up solving the first problem by using a sprite instead, and converting the Texture2D to a sprite. I don't know if that is a performant way to do it, so if anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear it. I still haven't figured out the 2nd issue.